# Is it possible to implement user search function using firebase auth?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I wonder how to do user management using Firebase. I have completed the implementation of the authentication process using firebase auth, but is it developed in a way that additionally stores user information in Firestore to perform a user search function? I wonder if general users can use the user search function using the Firebase auth SDK.

Also, I'm curious about how the user operation on the client-side using Firebase is currently performed.

Comment: [+] I wonder if the development method of using firebase auth only as an authentication method and registering user information in firestore once more is correct.

Comment: So you have added the possibility to add data to Firestore or not? If yes, what exactly are you worried about? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: When firebase auth is processed, user information is also recorded in firestore. I was wondering if this method is correct, and I was wondering if it is possible to get user information from the auth function and manage users more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only register or verify the user using auth service and if you want to search user you have to store user data in real-time or firestore.

Answer (score 0):

> When Firebase auth is processed, user information is also recorded in Firestore. I was wondering if this method is correct.

Yes, that's correct. That's actually a common approach when it comes to storing user data. Once the user is authenticated grab the corresponding data and store it in the database. You can either use [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database).

> I was wondering if it is possible to get user information from the auth function and manage users more efficiently.

I'm not aware of a more efficient way of doing that.